# ....Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

I am working on a signup page.

I want to copy a file to another directory via the copy function:

It makes a folder with a variable as the name like so:

```
mkdir($skool, 0700);
```

Then I make variables for the source and the destination and then copy them like so:

```
$source = 'indexa.php'; 
  

$destination = 'localhost/school/choose/$skool/indexa.php'; 
  
if( !copy($source, $destination) ) { 
    echo "File can't be copied! \n"; 
} 
else { 
    echo "File has been copied! \n"; 
}
```

I am using that `skool` variable, note.

I know this file exists but it flags up the following error:

```
copy(localhost/school/choose/indexa.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in the file on line 148
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong: please help!

Comment: 1) You seem to use HTTP hostname where it expects directory. 2) Variables don’t normally get passed to string enclosed by single quotes.

Comment: Do you really have a folder called `localhost` on your server? Remember that the file paths need to be server-based, not web-based.

Comment: fixed that but it still syas nothing

Comment: when you use the copy function, that creates a new file, right?

Comment: What does https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php show for `$source`?

Comment: Update your question with the fixes have applied. Because at this point it's no telling what you really tried from comments.

Comment: You should always use absolute pathes, with a '/' in front, or with the use of `__DIR__` constant

Comment: Remove the `/` before `/school` if its actually a relative path in the path of your script. You removed the `localhost/` as advised but you kept the leading `/` so remove that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work correctly because variable $skool inside single quotes

```
$destination = 'localhost/school/choose/$skool/indexa.php';
```

Try to take out a variable like this:

```
$destination = 'localhost/school/choose/' . $skool . '/indexa.php';
```

Comment: I have added a double quote but it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you checked that mkdir created the folder in the correct location?

Comment: yes i creates the folder in thecorretc location

Comment: Ok, can you debug the $destination variable and send it here?

Comment: im not sure how to debug it

Comment: var_dump($destination)

Comment: it syas so:
```
string(47) "/school/choose/Cooper Middle Sachool/indexa.php"
```
Cooper Middle Sachool is my variable

Comment: @ModzyWodzy Why have space in file paths???